# About the definition of holomorphic function

Tags: complex-analysis, definition, holomorphic-functions

So I was aware that in my complex analysis textbook, holomorphic/analytic function is defined by **complex differentiability** in the neighborhood of any point in the domain. Then, in later chapters, the book introduces series.

But, as I'm doing a maths project elsewhere, I wonder if holomorphic functions can be defined first by having a complex power series converging to the function, and have the differentiability deduced from this definition, and every other theorems about analytic functions in complex analysis afterwards?

Hope somebody could guide me to understand the underlying logic behind those concepts, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A convergent power series is always differrentiable, so you could do as you said.

In standard terminology, an **analytic** function is defined as a function with a convergent power series, while a **holomorphic** function is defined as one which is complex differrentiable. I.e., the definition starts *both* ways. An important result in complex analysis is that the two classes of functions exactly coincide, i.e., every analytic function is holomorphic and vice versa, so the two names get used interchangeably. Once you show this result, you can proceed the same way regardless of which definition you began with.

Comment: Hmmmm... I see, this is clarifying.

Comment: "I.e., the definition starts _both_ ways." That's a strange way to put it.

Comment: @zhw. It certainly is. But I think it gets the point across rhetorically.